# How to change the number of transactions generated by AXI Traffic Generator 3.0

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I tried to use a Xilinx IP AXI Traffic Generator(3.0) in Data Mode with one shot checked in. It generates 256 transactions. Is it possible to change the number of transactions? Following are the screenshot of the IP Gui:
[image]

Regards,
Anant Chetan

Comment: It writes to the external DDR memory, I would not be able to share the complete block design. I could measure the number of transactions using the Axi Performance Monitor (PS instances). (Xilinx zcu102 evaluation kit)

Comment: Under `DATA Mode->Pattern Options` change the `Traffic Pattern` parameter to `Random` instead of `Fixed`. Then you can choose from different Transfer Lengths